# Html: Contenteditable how to detect before deleting element after pressing backspace?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am making a text editor with `<div contenteditable>`. I want to prompt a confirmation message before the user deleting image element inside the editor. So when the user press backspace, before deleting the image element, there should be a prompt "Are you sure you want to delete the image?".

How can I do this?

Comment: Please post code for what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Event listener `keydown` can be added to that `<div contenteditable>` element. `Keydown` and `keypress` events takes place before the content is changed and `event.preventDefault()` can be used to stop the content before editing.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("elem").addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
    if( event.key=='Backspace' ){
      //your condition check can be given here
      if( confirm('are you sure you want to delete') ){
        return;
      }else{
        event.preventDefault();      
      }

    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.edit-elem{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="edit-elem" id="elem"></div>
```

Comment: Yes this is it. How can I detect the image tag that will be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

**Is this what you want?**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.remove').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('Are You Sure?');
  });
  
  $(document).on('keyup','div', function(e){
     console.log(e.keyCode);
     if(e.keyCode == '8'){
       alert('You have pressed backspace');
     }
  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable>
 <input type="file" class="image" name="image"/>
 <button type="button" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
```